# Simplifying Conditional Statement [Perl]

Tags: perl, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d matrix and I need to check if several elements equals a value (target value could be different for each element in the future).

Is there any way to simplify the if conditional at the end? I am hoping there would be some way to setup a 'conditional' matrix and compare them while ignoring elements that don't matter in the condition.

Any hints?

currently my code is:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

#fancy matrix
my @matrix; 

#set to a blank 3d test matrix
for my $i (0 .. 6) {
    for my $j (0 .. 6) {
        for my $k  (0 .. 2) {
            $matrix[$i][$j][$k] = 0;
        }
    }
}

#set some values for matrix

for my $j (0..2, 4..6) {
    my $i = 4;
    for my $k  (0 .. 2) {
        $matrix[$i][$j][$k] = 1;
    }
}
for my $i (0..2, 4..6) {
    my $j = 4;
    for my $k  (0 .. 2) {
        $matrix[$i][$j][$k] = 1;
    }
}

#the conditional problem child
if ($matrix[0][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[0][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[0][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[1][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[1][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[1][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[2][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[2][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[2][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[5][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[5][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[5][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[6][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[6][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[6][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][0][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][0][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][0][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][1][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][1][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][1][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][2][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][2][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][2][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][4][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][5][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][5][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][5][2] == 1 and $matrix[4][6][0] == 1 and $matrix[4][6][1] == 1 and $matrix[4][6][2] == 1) {
    print "it worked";
}

<stdin>;
```

edit note: If the way I'm approaching it is the best (doubt it), is there at least a way to make the if condition readable (not 36 compares on a single line)?

Comment: Are you looking for a more readable way, for a shorter way or for a faster at run-time way?

Comment: run-time would be best, if this is the best then readable for sure. A way to have a conditional matrix would be sick action tho.

Comment: For one thing, you can spread your condition over multiple lines to improve readability. And any `for` loop starting from `0` with a `<=` in the condition makes me nervous.

Comment: @melpomene what's the risk in that? Also I was betting that someone would call the variable being declared in the for loop... I lost the bet.

Comment: Well, a loop from `0` to `<= 6` iterates 7 times. Usually I see `< 7` to express this. `<=` often indicates an off-by-one bug.

Comment: I'd actually use a `foreach my $i ( 3 .. 6 )` which is more natural to read.

Comment: @melpomene I do that so I see the max value of the index. I'll have to try what simbabque suggested.

Comment: @simbabque True, iterating directly over a range is the best solution. (Personally I find `for my $i (3 .. 6)` slightly more natural because "for my i" is valid English whereas "for each my i" is not, but I don't care much either way.)

Comment: I've tidied your `if` statement to make it more readable and wonder if the values are correct. You have `$matrix[2][4][0]` in there twice and `$matrix[4][3][0]` three times. Is there an algorithm that says which cells need to be tested?

Comment: @Borodin it's true i just copypasta the conditional and modified it real quick. The logic that follows the comment "set some values for matrix" is the logic to build the conditional matrix.

Comment: @UpTide: Okay, but you're sure about those loops? It's clear that the first two `for` loops can be combined as `for (my $j = 0; $j<=6; $j++) { ... }` and similarly the third and fourth `for` loops. Was there a reason to split these up?

Comment: @Borodin yeah. when I was changing the for loops to the new syntax, I spotted that. Should be corrected now. `$matrix[3][3][0 .. 2]` should be 0

Comment: @UpTide: "the new syntax"?

Comment: @borodin `for (my $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {}` to `for my $i (0 .. 2) {}`

Comment: @UpTide: Ah. Got you. My copy of your question hadn't refreshed. You know you can write `for my $j (0..2, 4..6) { ... }` right?

Comment: @Borodin u rockin my world right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you build an array of references to all the matrix elements in the subset. Then you can both set and test them in simple `for` loops

Here my array of references is called `@cells`. I've also used the `all` function from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util), which allows all the tests to be made in a single call, and will short-circuit as soon as any test fails

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'all';

my @matrix;
my @cells;

# Initialise the matrix to all zeroes

for my $i (0 .. 6) {
    for my $j (0 .. 6) {
        for my $k  (0 .. 2) {
            $matrix[$i][$j][$k] = 0;
        }
    }
}

# Build an array of references to a subset of the cells
#
for my $i ( 0 .. 2, 4 .. 6 ) {
    push @cells, \$matrix[$i][4][$_] for 0 .. 2;
}

for my $j ( 0 .. 2, 4 .. 6 ) {
    push @cells, \$matrix[4][$j][$_] for 0 .. 2;
}

$$_ = 1 for @cells; # Set all the cells in the subset to 1

# Test that all cells in the subset are == 1
#
if ( all { $$_ == 1 } @cells ) {
    print "It worked\n";
}
```

Comment: what is `$$_` in `if ( all { $$_ == 1 } @cells)`?

Comment: @UpTide: It's the same as in `$$_ = 1 for @cells` above. Both `for` and `all` set `$_` to each reference in `@cells` in turn, and `$$_` dereferences `$_` as a scalar. In the `for` loop it's assigned to, and in `all` it's compared with 1.

Comment: using the _ scares me (because I don't know what it references when it's used, like what makes the `$$_` pull from `@cells` and not something else). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: so if someone else doesn't know what `$$_` means; because `@cells` is an array of references `$_` would be the reference, not the value. `$$_` gets the value of the reference. (at least that's how I'm understanding it)

Comment: @UpTide: That's right. And you won't get far in Perl if you avoid `$_`! `for` sets the context, so `$_` can only ever be elements of `@cells` there.

Comment: why is it pulling from `@cells` and not something else?

Comment: Because that's what you've written. `for @cells` sets `$_` to each element of the array in turn. The same applies to `all`

Comment: *"if I need to not check index 1 in the third dimension how would I do this?"* For this answer you would just build `@cells` differently, using `push @cells, \$matrix[$i][4][$_] for 0, 2` (instead of `0 .. 2`)

Comment: Doesn't it collide with @_ in subroutines? It seems so odd `sub foo { my @test = ("boop"); print $test[$_[$_]] for (0);}`

Comment: @UpTide: This is pretty fundamental to Perl. `$_` and `@_` are completely separate variables, just like `$x` and `@x`. An element of array `@x` is a scalar, so it uses a dollar as well as an index, so the first element of `@x` is `$x[0]`. All of this is explained in Perl's excellent documentation [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Comment: I used your pushing references into `@cells` then I check `@cells` with `for my $element (@cells) {if ($$element == 1)  {print "works.";}}`

Comment: @UpTide: That's different from your original code. It will print `works.` 36 times -- once for each element of `@cells`. Why don't you like to use `all`?

Comment: avoiding `use List::Util 'all';`

Comment: @UpTide: I don't understand. You don't want to use `all` because you want to avoid the `use` statement?

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it **more readable** (but not faster) is to use `eq_deeply` from [Test::Deep's](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep) [Test::Deep::NoTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep::NoTest).

You pass it two data structures and it tells you if they are equal. And if you only know half of what the structure should be like, you can use the nifty helper functions that let you ignore parts of it.

```
use Test::Deep::NoTest;

my $equal = eq_deeply( $matrix,
    [
        [
            [ 1, 0, ],
            [ 0, 0, ],
        ],
        [
            [ 1, 1, ],
            [ 0, 1, ],
        ],
        [
            [ 1, 1, ],
            [ 0, 1, ],
        ],
    ]
);

if ($equal) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: I may be slightly retarded, where are these helper functions?

Comment: @UpTide they are documented in Test::Deep. Stuff like `ignore`, `bag` and so on. Just go through the docs. This thing is meant for unit tests, so it gives a lot of freedom and you can build very specific comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `map` and `all` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) (or [`List::AllUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AllUtils)), you could shorten the conditional to this:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'all';

if ( all { $_ == 1 } map { @{ $matrix[$_][4] }, @{ $matrix[4][$_] } } 0..2, 4..6 ) { 
    say "It worked!";
}
```

If you're not familiar with maps and dereferencing syntax in perl, it can look a little confusing. The `map` creates a list of the entries from `matrix[0..2,4..6][4]` and `matrix[4][0..2,4..6]`. All those values then get passed to the `all` block which checks that all values received are equal to 1.

Because `matrix[n][n]` would return an ARRAY ref, you have to dereference it, eg. `@{ $array_ref }`

Comment: This doesn't result in the same list of array elements as the OP's code. Your code examines 42 elements whereas the OP's looks as 36.

Comment: Does that check if each entry in the third dimension is 1? Making `@matrix` to be able to pass the conditional is just for testing. When I use the conditional I can't assume that `@matrix[0][0][0] = @matrix[0][0][1] = @matrix[0][0][2]`

Comment: Borodin, OP's code was different when originally posted. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Joshua can you link me the cpan for `all`? Either Strawberry Perl doesn't have it, or I just need to reference it.

Comment: The module is [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) <-- click

Comment: @Joshua if I need to not check index 1 in the third dimension how would I do this? as in change the condition so this is fine:`@matrix[1][4][1] = 0`

Comment: It could be done, but it can get messy for other conditionals. I have only solved the most simplest of conditionals (ie, are all rows/columns in a given dimension equal to some number). If you have more complex conditionals to check, simbabque's answer might be better. I'd also guess there might already be some good modules on CPAN that make multi-dimensional matrix operations easier.